# Unbounded and sequences tending to infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there any difference between unbounded sequence and sequences tending to infinity?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. An unbounded sequence might not tend towards anything. For example, $(-1)^n n$ is unbounded, but does not tend towards infinity.

It is not even true that an unbounded sequence of positive real numbers tends to infinity. Consider the sequence $a_n$ defines by $a_{2n + 1} = 0$ and $a_{2n} = n$ for each natural number $n$. $(a_n)$ is also unbounded, but also does not tend toward infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Unbounded sequence don't have a limit necessarily.

For example, $(-1)^n n$ is unbounded sequence, which doesn't have a limit

Answer (score 0):

$0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8...$