# Can we say a function is "unbounded" when we mean it''s tending to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, upper-lower-bounds

I'm watching the Limits series on Khan Academy. In many videos Sal repeatedly says that although some people say that functions that tend to infinity have a limit infinity. (For example, in [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-1/cs1-limits-and-continuity/modal/v/infinite-limits-and-asymptotes) video, the says that the function $ y = \frac {2}{x-1} $ (here's a link to the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d1ioaqbnnn)) is unbounded as x approaches 1 from the left side, although "some" people would say that the function is tending towards infinity (i.e., the $ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \infty $.

Over a series of videos, I caught hold of that argument and always said that function don't tend towards infinity; they're just unbounded. But, in a different video ([here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-1/cs1-limits-and-continuity/modal/v/introduction-to-infinite-limits)), Sal essentially says:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1{x^2} = \infty $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac 1{x} = \infty $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac 1{x} = -\infty $$

There is an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887018/unbounded-and-sequences-tending-to-infinity) that says that unbounded sequences don't always tend to infinity. So it seems that we can't say that the limit of unbounded functions as x tends to some number is infinity -- what I'm confused about, and my question is: When do we ever say that the limit of some function is infinity? Specifically, are the limits of the above functions $ \frac 1x $ and $$ \frac 1{x^2} $$ correct? Or are they unbounded? If we can say that these limits are correct, why can't we say this: $$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac 2{x-1} = - \infty $$

Comment: Things that tend to infinity are unbounded, but unbounded things do not always tend to infinity. Tending to infinity means more: it means it is both unbounded and at the same time doesn't "go back down".

Comment: One of the limits is wrong: $\frac 1 {x^{2}}$ is a positive function so it cannot tend to $-\infty$. All other limits are correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy -- Thank you, edited.

Comment: @Arthur -- Thanks, that explains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Arthur said in the comments, functions being "bounded" and "tending to infinity" mean different things. If $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$, then it tends to infinity and gets arbitrarily large in the process. Hence it is not bounded, so there does not exist real numbers $a,b$ so that $f(x)\in[a,b]$ for all $x$ in the domain. However, if a function is unbounded it does not necessarily tend to infinity. In fact, the limit need not even exist. Just consider $f(x)=\sin(1/x)/x$.

Answer (score 4):

A *necessary* condition for a function to have infinite limit is that it is unbounded.

More precisely, if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$, then $f$ is upper unbounded; if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=-\infty$, then $f$ is lower unbounded. (*The limit in the previous statements can also be one-sided.*)

One could be more precise and say that $f$ must be (upper/lower) unbounded in *every* punctured neighborhood of $c$ (or punctured right/left neighborhood of $c$).

This essentially follows from the definition.

However, this condition is by no means sufficient. Consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}
$$
Then this function is unbounded in every punctured neighborhood of $0$, but its limit is neither $\infty$ nor $-\infty$.

Restricting to the limit from the right or the left doesn't improve the situation.

Confusing “unbounded” with “has infinite limit” may be very dangerous.